# Variables not working in function python (what's wrong in my code)

Tags: python, function, if-statement, variables

Variables not working in functions, why? What's wrong in My Code? I checked many times but everything is current. Please Help

```
Mode = "Copy"


#mode
def runRclone():
  if Mode == "Copy":
    print ("cpy")
    modeFinal = "copy"
  elif Mode == "Move":
    modeFinal = "move"
  elif Mode == "Check Size":
    modeFinal = "size"
  else:
    modeFinal = "size"
    print("Some Thing is Wrong, Contact me!")

runRclone()

print(modeFinal)
```

**Output**

```
cpy
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-7ade1dfbd321> in <module>()
     42 runRclone()
     43 
---> 44 print(modeFinal)

NameError: name 'modeFinal' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call your function. modeFinal is defined in your function but not global. You can make your modeFInal global at the start of your function like `global modeFinal`.

```
Mode = "Copy"


#mode
def runRclone():
  global modeFinal
  if Mode == "Copy":
    print ("cpy")
    modeFinal = "copy"
  elif Mode == "Move":
    modeFinal = "move"
  elif Mode == "Check Size":
    modeFinal = "size"
  else:
    modeFinal = "size"
    print("Some Thing is Wrong, Contact me!")

runRclone()

print(modeFinal)
```

Another option would be to return modeFinal in your function then store the function output in variable.

```
Mode = "Copy"


#mode
def runRclone():
  if Mode == "Copy":
    print ("cpy")
    modeFinal = "copy"
  elif Mode == "Move":
    modeFinal = "move"
  elif Mode == "Check Size":
    modeFinal = "size"
  else:
    modeFinal = "size"
    print("Some Thing is Wrong, Contact me!")
   return modeFinal
mdFinal = runRclone()

print(mdFinal)
```

Answer (score 1):

modeFinal is not being returned and is scoped  to be within the function, so when you call `print(modeFinal)`  it cannot find it. You could return it at the end of your if/elif statement

```
Mode = "Copy"


#mode
def runRclone():
  if Mode == "Copy":
    print ("cpy")
    modeFinal = "copy"
  elif Mode == "Move":
    modeFinal = "move"
  elif Mode == "Check Size":
    modeFinal = "size"
  else:
    modeFinal = "size"
    print("Some Thing is Wrong, Contact me!")

  return(modeFinal)

modeFinal = runRclone()

print(modeFinal)
```

Answer (score 1):

`modeFinal` is only visible within the **scope** of your function `runRclone()`. You could have your function return `modeFinal` as such :

```
Mode = "Copy"

#mode
def runRclone():
  if Mode == "Copy":
    print ("cpy")
    modeFinal = "copy"
  elif Mode == "Move":
    modeFinal = "move"
  elif Mode == "Check Size":
    modeFinal = "size"
  else:
    modeFinal = "size"
    print("Some Thing is Wrong, Contact me!")

  return modeFinal

modeFinal = runRclone()

print(modeFinal)
```